# Transposing columns to rows Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a situation like following:

| ID | Old value.Carbon | Old value.Dioxide | New value.Carbon | New Value.Dioxide |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 34.89 | 13.45 | 56.66 | 11.11 |
| 456 | 12.13 | 55.66 | 66.88 | 12.33 |

My output that i want should be:( i want the column to be transposed to rows like following, i have renamed the fields as Old Value. and New Value. because i thought this might help but if you have any other ideas i am more than happy to try something different. Thanks a lot for all the help!

| ID | Field | New Value | Old Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Carbon | 56.66 | 34.89 |
| 123 | Dioxide | 11.11 | 13.45 |
| 456 | Dioxide | 12.33 | 12.33 |
| 456 | Carbon | 66.88 | 12.13 |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reshape pandas DataFrame from wide to long by splitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74800328/reshape-pandas-dataframe-from-wide-to-long-by-splitting)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and a MultiIndex to reshape:

```
tmp = df.set_index('ID')
out = (tmp.set_axis(tmp.columns.str.capitalize()
                       .str.split('\.', expand=True),
                    axis=1)
          .rename_axis(columns=(None, 'Field'))
          .stack()
          .reset_index()       
      )
```

Output:

```
    ID    Field  Old value  New value
0  123   carbon      34.89      56.66
1  123  dioxide      13.45      11.11
2  456   carbon      12.13      66.88
3  456  dioxide      55.66      12.33
```

Comment: I have never used this ! Thanks a lot , that's amazing! Really appreciate it!:)

Answer (score 1):

One  option is with [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor
(df
.rename(columns=str.capitalize)
.pivot_longer(
    index='Id', 
    names_to=['.value', 'Field'], 
    names_sep='.', 
    sort_by_appearance=True)
)
    Id    Field  Old value  New value
0  123   carbon      34.89      56.66
1  123  dioxide      13.45      11.11
2  456   carbon      12.13      66.88
3  456  dioxide      55.66      12.33
```

with `pd.wide_to_long`:

```py
 tmp = df.set_index('ID').rename(columns=str.capitalize)
(pd
.wide_to_long(
    tmp.reset_index(), 
    stubnames=['Old value', 'New value'], 
    sep='.', 
    suffix='.+', 
    i='ID', 
    j='Field')
.reset_index()
) 
    ID    Field  Old value  New value
0  123   carbon      34.89      56.66
1  456   carbon      12.13      66.88
2  123  dioxide      13.45      11.11
3  456  dioxide      55.66      12.33
```